# Binding bootstrap datetimepicker to knockoutmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datetimepicker

Im using a bootstrap datetimepicker to input appointment datetimes to a knockout viewmodel. the viewmodel has an object appointment which holds the observable values for all appointment object. Im sending the appointment to the controller via an ajax call, however after many null values for my dates i found that you must create a custom binding for the datepicker. after implementing the custom binding on the git page of the datepicker i am still receiving null values for both the start and end dates.

Have i implemented the custom binding incorrectly?

Code:

View:

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Appointment</h4>
        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-3'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='startdatepicker'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-bind="date: appointment.start, format: 'DD MMM YYYY'" /><span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.End, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-3'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='enddatepicker'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" data-bind="date: appointment.end, format: 'DD MMM YYYY'" /><span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.End, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Scripts section at bottom of view

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval",
 "/Scripts/ViewModels/AppointmentFormViewModel.js")
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#startdatepicker').datetimepicker();
        $('#enddatepicker').datetimepicker();

    });

    var viewModel = new AppointmentFormViewModel(@Html.HtmlConvertToJson(Model));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
}
```

Knockout viewmodel

```
function AppointmentFormViewModel(appointment) {
var self = this;
self.saveCompleted = ko.observable(false);
self.sending = ko.observable(false);

self.isCreating = appointment.id == 0;
self.appointment = {
    id: appointment.id,
    start: ko.observable(appointment.start),
    end: ko.observable(appointment.end),
    text: ko.observable(appointment.text),
    clientid: ko.observable(appointment.clientid),
    employeeid: ko.observable(appointment.employeeid),
    roomid: ko.observable(appointment.roomid),
};


ko.bindingHandlers.date = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'change', function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (element.value !== null && element.value !== undefined && element.value.length > 0) {
                value(element.value);
            }
            else {
                value('');
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);


        var pattern = allBindings.format || 'DD/MM/YYYY';

        var output = "-";
        if (valueUnwrapped !== null && valueUnwrapped !== undefined && valueUnwrapped.length > 0) {
            output = moment(valueUnwrapped).format(pattern);
        }

        if ($(element).is("input") === true) {
            $(element).val(output);
        } else {
            $(element).text(output);
        }
    }
};
```

here is the appointment model object that was sent from the knockout viewmodel
as you can see the date time is not what was selected

[image]

Here is how it posted to server
is creating is a variable to determine whether the form is editing or creating an appointment

```
self.appointment.__RequestVerificationToken = form[0].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: (self.isCreating) ? 'Create' : 'Edit',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: ko.toJS(self.appointment)
    })
```

Comment: I can see the start and end values alright. Are you using `self.appointment.start()` and `self.appointment.end()`?

Comment: @Neps I'm not sure i follow you do you mean in the viewmodel?            start: ko.observable(self.appointment.start()),

Comment: You said you're "receiving null values". What does the ajax call to the server look like?

Comment: @Neps i added a screenshot of the breakpoint where you can see what i mean hope this helps

Comment: I see. So the problem is _probably_ in either the asp.net model binding or how the data is sent. You might want to include how the data is posted back to the server.

Comment: @Neps im not sure if it s the post ive added it anyways i think its in the model binding but i don't know where?